# Unsure why print function isn't happening

Tags: python

I was given a code, and inside it there are 2 points where I have to input my own code to "solve" the problem. Everything seems fine, but when I type in something after choice 2, it simply resets back to the beginning without printing what I requested it to print.

```py
itemsInBackpack = ["book", "computer", "keys", "travel mug"]

while True:
    print("Would you like to:")
    print("1. Add an item to the backpack?")
    print("2. Check if an item is in the backpack?")
    print("3. Quit")
    userChoice = input()

    if(userChoice == "1"):
        print("What item do you want to add to the backpack?")
        itemToAdd = input()
        ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######
        itemsInBackpack.append(itemToAdd)
        ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######

    if(userChoice == "2"):
        print("What item do you want to check to see if it is in the backpack?")
        itemToCheck = input()
        ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######
        if itemToCheck == itemsInBackpack:
            print('That item is in the backpack.')
        ####### YOUR CODE HERE ######
```

I left out the choice 3 where it does a sys.exit, just didn't think it was needed as it isn't what I am having issues with.

So under userChoice == 2 I added code that if whatever is entered == an item in the backpack list, to print the message. Problem is, it doesn't do that, it just resets back to the original 3 choices, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing happens if that item is not in your backpack, so what you are typing in is probably not in your backpack. Try adding an else statement to print that the item is not in the backpack.

Answer (score 3):

You are not checking that an item is in the backpack, you are checking that the item is equal to your backpack. Use the following

```
if itemToCheck in itemsInBackpack:
```

instead of:

```
if itemToCheck == itemsInBackpack:
```

In addition, notice that you if somebody enters `"BOOK"`, "booK" or any variation of lowercase/uppercase, `itemToCheck in itemsInBackpack` will be false even if you have `itemsInBackpack` to be `itemsInBackpack = ["book", "computer", "keys", "travel mug"]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `if itemToCheck == itemsInBackpack:`

`itemsInBackpack` is a list, so this should be `if itemToCheck in itemsInBackpack:`